# SPO how to add Organization Chart on communication site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, communication-site, organization-chart

I would like to know the best organization chart webpart that I could easily install in my **Communication site** **(Modern Experience)**.

It should be user friendly, with nice theme as well as easily editable. Also it should work with list as well as Active Directory.

Similar to this:
[image: Organization Chart]

Any suggestion how to achieve it in **Modern Experience** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no organization chart webpart in SharePoint modern page. You could vote on User Voice here:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/17953939-make-the-delve-organization-chart-available-as-a-w

You need to use spfx webparts to achieve this, here are some demos for you:

https://github.com/joaojmendes/React-Tree-Organization-Chart
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-organisationchart

Comment: Thank you i will check the demos you mentioned ! Maybe i could use them.